# Remapping CapsLock key

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, remapping, capslock

I've remapped <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key to work like this :

<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> = <kbd>Left arrow key</kbd>
<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> = <kbd>Down arrow key</kbd>
etc.

I've used xmodmap (as explained in [Mapping Super+hjkl to arrow keys under X](https://superuser.com/questions/96299/mapping-superhjkl-to-arrow-keys-under-x/111968#111968)).

The problem is that I can't seem to be able to make following key combinations work :

Expected: <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> = <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow key</kbd>
Actual: <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> = does nothing.
etc.

Do you have any ideas how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your xmodmap changes.

Comment: I am not a linux person but, probably xmodmap cannot detect CapsLock+J key sequence because you have held the Shift key down. And I think it wont be just shift. Test any key on keyboard say ctrl, alt, pgdn etc..

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but the best way to approach this would be to see what events are being fired when you press the combinations you're interested in. To do this, install **xev** and try out the various combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and asked it over on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533719/custom-keyboard-layout-to-use-h-j-k-l-as-arrows-not-working-properly/1048906#1048906). 
The issue can be solved by:

#### setting the preserve parameter

edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/iso9995` and add `preserve[Shift+LevelThree] = Shift;` such that the contents of the file looks like:

```
  partial default xkb_types "default" {

// A key type which can be used to implement
// an ISO9995-style level-three shift.

virtual_modifiers LevelThree;

type "THREE_LEVEL" {
    modifiers = Shift+LevelThree;
    map[None] = Level1;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[LevelThree] = Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree] = Level3;
    preserve[Shift+LevelThree] = Shift;
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Level3";
    };
};
```

#### customize the symbols file for the desired layout

Edit the keyboard layout file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` as following (adapting to your own needs)

```
key <AC06>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [   h,   H, Left  ]   }; 
key <AC07>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [   j,   J, Down  ]   }; 
key <AC08>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [   k,   K, Up    ]   }; 
key <AC09>  { type="THREE_LEVEL", [   l,   L, Right ]   };
```

and not like

```
 ....
 key { [ j, J, Down, Down ] };
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like it may be correct. I cannot accept it, though. I don't have any Ubuntu machine right now to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that capslock and shift are nearly the same in your keyboard hardware, it may be that your capslock key just permanently triggers the shift key.

Comment: You could probably check this by pressing Shift + J/ Shift + K, and seeing if they trigger your remapped keys Caps Lock key functions.

Comment: Shift + J / Shift + K is not affected by my remapping.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood well how it works, try in the keyboard specification file to explicit say what you want for example for he shifted ation, for example

```
key { [ j, J, Down, Next ] };
key { [ k, K, Up, Prior ] };
```

to have PageDn and PageUp --- I cannot chek it now, but should work.

Answer (score -1):

I've tested many suggested methods but I've found this by far simplest to implement and understand. Create file `nano ~/.my_keyboard`, paste the code below (change key mapping according to you plan) and run `xmodmap ~/.my_keyboard`.

```
clear lock
keycode 66 = Mode_switch

keysym h = h H Left Left hstroke Hstroke
keysym j = j J Down Down dead_hook dead_horn
keysym k = k K Up Up lstroke ampersand
keysym l = l L Right Right lstroke Lstroke
```

This disables standard `Caps Lock` functionality and remaps key to `Mode_switch` modifier. To reset xmodmap settings you can run `setxkbmap`.

Here is the [original](https://shellhell.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/hello-world/) solution I've addapted.

Comment: You’ve tested … against what requirements?  This answer doesn’t look like it’s even trying to answer this question.  The OP wants J = Left; you're mapping J to Down.  The OP wants K = Down; you're mapping K to Up.  The OP wants Caps Lock to combine with J and K, and you're disabling it?  How is this even close to being an answer to this question?

Comment: OP wanted to have additional arrow keys accessible using Caps Lock + some-keys. He specifically wanted this remapping to work with Shift key so that it behvaes like with regular arrow keys (selecting using Shift + arrow keys). Link of the partial solution he provided disables normal functionality of Caps Lock as well, and since OP didn't mention that as a problem I assumed that is OK. Mapping specific keys to arrows is trivial to change, but it is my mistake here... I wanted to do exactly the same thing so I think I have idea what OP had in mind.