# Remap Keys via Command Line in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, remapping

I'm trying to write a script that will replicate my OS X setup. In particular I want to remap the arrow keys to <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>.

The technique seems to be similar to this [Linux solution](https://superuser.com/a/111968/194670), except the key file to modify is found in `/usr/X11/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. It's not really working as expected though and seems to be mapping the option key.

How can I remap keys via the command line in OS X?

Comment: What are you trying to replicate?

Comment: The keyboard mappings that would otherwise have to be configured through the GUI.

Comment: Which GUI? The preferences of the Terminal application? Most applications'  settings are already stored as simple files and can easily be transferred to another machine. Additionally, Terminal allows exporting and importing settings.

Comment: I'm just looking for a system-wide way to remap keys via the command-line. By GUI I meant Keyboard settings in System Preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application-specific keyboard shortcuts like those from System Preferences are stored in the preference files of the corresponding application in `/Users/username/Library/Preferences/`, in the top-level `NSUserKeyEquivalents` key.

[image]

[image]

Those files can be read and written using the `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` and `defaults` programs on the command line.

```
$ defaults read com.apple.Automator NSUserKeyEquivalents
{
    "Hide Library" = "@$l";
    "Show Library" = "@$l";
}
$ defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "About Terminal" '^@$a'
```

[image]

Symbols and their meanings:

- `@` is <kbd>Command</kbd>
- `$` is <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- `^` is <kbd>Control</kbd>
- `~` is <kbd>Option</kbd>

Additionally, you can simply copy these files to other machines to take your user preferences with you.

Comment: How would I find the modifier key? I changed Caps Lock to control, how can I find this setting via command line?

Comment: These days in Mojave, one can change modifier keys in the Keyboard preference pane. But I'm at a loss for how to do this from the command line. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Using [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), you could save this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::H, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::H, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::J, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::J, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::K, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::K, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::L, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::L, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

Leaving out  `| ModifierFlag::NONE` would also change for example ⌥⌘H to ←.

See the source for the [key code constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/version_8.0.0/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/).

If you want to fully automate the configuration, you can enable the setting with `/Library/org.pqrs/KeyRemap4MacBook/app/KeyRemap4MacBook_cli.app/Contents/MacOS/KeyRemap4MacBook_cli enable private.test`.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but I didn't understand how I would do the configuration from a command line script...