# How to make all applications respect my modified xkb layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xkb

I don't like jumping between the main keyboard and the movement keys, so I added the following to my xkb layout file.

```
hidden partial xkb_symbols "movement"
{
    key <AD08> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Up,          Up          ] };
    key <AC08> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Down,        Down        ] };
    key <AC07> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Left,        Left        ] };
    key <AC09> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Right,       Right       ] };
    key <AD09> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Prior,       Prior       ] };
    key <AB09> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Next,        Next        ] };
    key <AB07> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Home,        Home        ] };
    key <AB08> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, End,         End         ] };
    key <AC06> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Delete,      Delete      ] };
}
```

Then I include these to the layout at a later point in the file. Now I should have the cursor keys accessible through AltGr + j,k,l,i (or h,t,n,c as I'm using dvorak) etc. This works in many cases (like Firefox, urxvt, Eclipse, the main text area of LyX) but some programs do nothing when I try to, say, move the cursor using these "shortcuts" (like NetBeans and LyX dialogs).

So, is there a way to make these other programs also respect my wishes? And why are they not working in the first place? I'm not using a DE; only the Awesome WM.

**Edit:**

- [Here](http://pastebin.com/p0Pjy7XV) is a full but simplified keyboard layout file. I have this as `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/nonpop` and I load it with `setxkbmap nonpop`.
- I noticed that in MonoDevelop moving around works but selecting does not. That is, if I press Shift+Right then text is selected as usual, but if I press AltGr+Shift+n then the cursor just moves without selecting. For example in Firefox both ways can be used for selecting.
- [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension) in the end they talk about *overlays* which looks like something that could perhaps be a solution but I haven't figured out how to use them.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but if you don't manage to get an answer despite the bounty you put up you could try asking at [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), a more Unix/Linux-centered Stackexchange site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Why are they not working

According to the [ArchWiki’s article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension) that you mentioned:

- X server gets *keycodes* from the input device and converts them to the
  *state* and *keysym*.

  - *state* is the bitmask of the X modifiers (Ctrl/Shift/etc).
  - *keysym* is (according to `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`) the integer
    that

    > identify characters or functions associated with each key (e.g., via
    >   the visible engraving) of a keyboard layout.

    Each printable character has its own keysym, like `plus`, `a`, `A`, or
    `Cyrillic_a`, but other keys also generate their keysyms, like
    `Shift_L`, `Left` or `F1`.
- The application in the key press/release events gets all of this information.

  Some applications track keysyms like `Control_L` by themselves, others just
  look for the modifier bits in the *state*.

So what happens, when you press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>:

- You press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. Application gets KeyPressed event with keycode
  108 (`<RALT>`) and keysym 0xfe03 (`ISO_Level3_Shift`), state is 0.
- You press <kbd>j</kbd> (which maps to “h” in dvorak without modifiers).
  Application gets KeyPressed event with keycode 44 (`<AC07>`), keysym 0xff51
  (`Left`) and state 0x80 (modifier Mod5 is on).
- You release <kbd>j</kbd>. The application gets KeyRelease event for the key
  `<AC07>`/`Left` with the same parameters.
- Then release <kbd>AltGr</kbd> — KeyRelease event for AltGr. (By the way,
  the state here is still 0x80, but that doesn’t matter.)

This can be seen if you run `xev` utility.

So, that all means that, although the application gets the same keysym code
(`Left`) as from the normal key `<LEFT>`, it also gets the keysym code and
modifier state from the AltGr. Most probably, those programs that don’t work,
watch the modifiers and don’t want to work when some are active.

### How to make them work

Apparently, we can’t change every program to not to look for modifiers. Then
the only option to escape this situation is to not generate modifiers’ keysyms
and state bits.

#### 1. Separate group

The only method that comes to my mind is: define cursor movement keys in a
separate group and switch, with a separate key press, to that group prior to
pressing the keys <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> (`h`,
`t`, `n`, `c`) (group latching is the preferred method for one time group
change, as I understand).

For example:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types { include "complete" };
    xkb_compatibility {
        include "complete"

        interpret ISO_Group_Latch { action = LatchGroup(group=2); };
    };
    xkb_symbols {
        include "pc+us(dvorak)+inet(evdev)"

        key <RALT> { [ ISO_Group_Latch ] };

        key <AC07> {
            type[Group2] = "ONE_LEVEL",
            symbols[Group2] = [ Left ]
        };
        key <AC08> {
            type[Group2] = "ONE_LEVEL",
            symbols[Group2] = [ Down ]
        };
        key <AC09> {
            type[Group2] = "ONE_LEVEL",
            symbols[Group2] = [ Right ]
        };
        key <AD08> {
            type[Group2] = "ONE_LEVEL",
            symbols[Group2] = [ Up ]
        };
    };
    xkb_geometry { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

Now, if you first press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and then (separately) one of the
movement keys, this should work.

However, this is not very useful, more appropriate would be to `LockGroup`
instead of latch and press AltGr before and after group switch. Even better may
be to `SetGroup` — then AltGr would select that group only while being pressed,
but that discloses to the applications AltGr’s keysym
(`ISO_Group_Shift`/`ISO_Group_Latch`/whatever is defined) (but modifier state
stays clean).

But... there is also a possibility left that the application also reads
keycodes (the codes of the real keys). Then it will notice the “fake” cursor keys.

#### 2. Overlay

The more “low-level” solution would be the *overlay* (as the same [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension)
describes).

*Overlay* simply means that some (real keyboard )key returns the keycode of
another key. The X server changes the keycode of a key and computes the
modifier state and the keysym for that new keycode, so the application
shouldn’t notice the change.

But overlays are very limited:

- There are only 2 overlay control bits in the X server (i.e. there can be
  maximum 2 overlays).
- Each key can have only 1 alternative keycode.

As for the rest, the implementation is quite similar to the method with a
separate group:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types { include "complete" };
    xkb_compatibility {
        include "complete"

        interpret Overlay1_Enable {
            action = SetControls(controls=overlay1);
        };
    };
    xkb_symbols {
        include "pc+us(dvorak)+inet(evdev)"

        key <RALT> {
            type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL",
            symbols[Group1] = [ Overlay1_Enable ]
        };
        key <AC07> { overlay1 = <LEFT> };
        key <AC08> { overlay1 = <DOWN> };
        key <AC09> { overlay1 = <RGHT> };
        key <AD08> { overlay1 = <UP> };
    };
    xkb_geometry { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

`SetControls` means change the control bit while the key is pressed and restore
it on the key release. There should be similar function `LatchControls`, but
`xkbcomp` gives me

```
Error:            Unknown action LatchControls
```

on keymap compilation.

(By the way, I also use dvorak and also have remapped some movement keysyms to
high levels of alphabetic keys. And also came across some broken functionality
(selection in Xfce notes and desktop switch by Ctrl-Alt-Left/Right). Thanks to
your question and this answer, now I know what an overlay is :).)

Comment: Thanks! I actually got another answer on [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153841/how-to-make-altgri-j-k-l-work-properly-as-cursor-keys) which at first seemed to be perfect but turned out some applications still misbehaved. This solution (overlays) works in those cases, too.

Comment: I just noticed that google chrom[e|ium] don't care about this either! :( Luckily I don't use them much.

Comment: @nonpop goddamn chromium… I've added an update to my reply https://superuser.com/a/1000320/521612

Comment: Amazing! I've searched for this for years! There's still a minor issue with Chromium where it interprets a keypress of `Overlay1_Enable`. I have the same symptom as here: https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-distro/issues/362

Comment: I just managed to fix the above issue. My home row arrow keys now work in Chromium as well! I needed the following change to this answer. https://gist.github.com/Tarrasch/1293692/revisions?diff=unified#diff-170987db8deaa0865033ae2715f45dce

Answer (score 6):

## How to make them work - Solution 3

### Using additional Levels and Action RedirectKey

Following solution uses the left Alt key to provide cursor keys on jkli, Home/End/PageUp/PageDown on uopö and a Delete on the Backspace.

The left Alt key remains usable for other purposes for all other keys (like for the application menu). The left Alt (Mod1) is removed from the modifier state when the cursor block is used so applications can't see it.

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes { 
        include "evdev+aliases(qwertz)" 
    };
    xkb_types { 
        include "complete"  
    };
    xkb_compat { 
        include "complete"
        interpret osfLeft {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfRight {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfUp {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<UP>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfDown {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<DOWN>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfBeginLine {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<HOME>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfEndLine {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<END>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfPageUp {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<PGUP>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfPageDown {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<PGDN>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
        interpret osfDelete {
            action = RedirectKey(keycode=<DELE>, clearmodifiers=Mod1);
        };
    };
    xkb_symbols { 
        include "pc+de(nodeadkeys)"
        include "inet(evdev)"
        include "compose(rwin)"
        key <LALT> {
            type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL",
            symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level5_Shift ]
        };
        modifier_map Mod1 { <LALT> };
        key <AC07> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ j, J, dead_belowdot, dead_abovedot, osfLeft, osfLeft, osfLeft, osfLeft ]
        };
        key <AC08> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ k, K, kra, ampersand, osfDown, osfDown, osfDown, osfDown ]
        };
        key <AC09> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ l, L, lstroke, Lstroke, osfRight, osfRight, osfRight, osfRight ]
        };
        key <AC10> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ odiaeresis, Odiaeresis, doubleacute, doubleacute, osfPageDown, osfPageDown, osfPageDown, osfPageDown ]
        };
        key <AD07> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ u, U, downarrow, uparrow, osfBeginLine, osfBeginLine, osfBeginLine, osfBeginLine ]
        };
        key <AD08> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ i, I, rightarrow, idotless, osfUp, osfUp, osfUp, osfUp ]
        };
        key <AD09> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ o, O, oslash, Oslash, osfEndLine, osfEndLine, osfEndLine, osfEndLine ]
        };
        key <AD10> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ p, P, thorn, THORN, osfPageUp, osfPageUp, osfPageUp, osfPageUp ]
        };
        key <BKSP> {
            type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC",
            symbols[Group1] = [ BackSpace, BackSpace, BackSpace, BackSpace, osfDelete, osfDelete, osfDelete, osfDelete ] 
        };
    };
    xkb_geometry { 
        include "pc(pc105)" 
    };
};
```

Comment: Holy moly! That actually works! It works around broken applications like Chromium. Can you explain what these osf definitions are? It seems that they're predefined so you can't name them randomly.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. It is so painful.

So the title is “How to make all applications respect my modified xkb layout?“. Well, I think the only way is to fix all of the programs that do it incorrectly. Let's do that!

Well, after reporting that bug in [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=256592) (**Update: I've tried the latest version and it works now!**), I thought that I will just keep reporting this bug for every application. Next application on the list was **Speedcrunch**.

However, after looking for similar bug reports I found [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/heldercorreia/speedcrunch/issues/472/custom-key-binding-is-not-always-honored). Someone else is having the same problem, great!

After reading the comments you will understand that this bug should be present in all QT apps. Here is a [QT bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36565). Not resolved, **but it seems like the issue is solved in Qt5**.

However, if you look at the comments, there's a workaround! Here is how it works. If you were doing this:

```
key <SPCE> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
```

Then you can change it to this:

```
key <SPCE> {
  type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
  symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
};
```

And it will actually solve the problem for some of the applications! For example, **Speedcrunch** now works for me! Yay!

### Summary

Right now any application should work correctly. If it doesn't, then you have to use `type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL"`. If you already have it, then you have to update your software. If it still does not work, then it is app-specific and you have to submit a bug report.

### UPDATE (2017-09-23)

As of today, all applications respect my keyboard layout. All except one.

Seriously, **keyboard handling in Chromium is garbage**. There are several problems with it:

- Shift selection does not with custom arrow keys (but arrow keys themselves work OK)
- If you have multiple layouts and on one of the layouts some key is special (e.g. arrows, Backspace, etc.), then on another layout this key will be fixed to whatever you have on your first layout. For example, if you have two layouts: `foo`,`bar` and some key does Backspace in `foo`, then it will keep working as Backspace in `bar` even if it is redefined there.

For years I ignored these problems by simply not using chromium. However, nowadays things tend to use [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron), which is unfortunately built on Chromium.

The right way to resolve this would be to submit a bug report in Chromium and hope for the best. I don't know how long it will take them to resolve an issue that is only affecting a couple of users… but that seems to be the only way out. The problem with this is that chromium actually works fine with `neo(de)` layout. Neo layout has arrow keys on level5, but I can't get it to work in my custom layout.

### Still-open bug reports:

- Pluma – https://github.com/mate-desktop/pluma/issues/17

Comment: Thanks for the info! The workaround doesn't help me so I guess I'll have to just report bugs and wait for qt5 conversions.

Answer (score 0):

A recent update broke my setup again. This time I found a completely different solution which so far seems to work: https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys. This daemon grabs the keyboard events before they get to *any* other handler, transforms them, and sends the new events to a virtual keyboard device, which the applications then read.

To make it work, I dropped all the movement key stuff from my xkb layout file and instead created the following `evdevremapkeys.yaml`:

```yaml
devices:
    - input_name: Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint
      input_phys: usb-0000:03:00.0-8/input0
      output_name: remap-kbd
      remappings:
          KEY_RIGHTALT:
              - modifier_group: altgr
      modifier_groups:
          altgr:
              KEY_J:
                  - KEY_LEFT
              KEY_L:
                  - KEY_RIGHT
              KEY_I:
                  - KEY_UP
              KEY_K:
                  - KEY_DOWN
              KEY_O:
                  - KEY_PAGEUP
              KEY_DOT:
                  - KEY_PAGEDOWN
              KEY_M:
                  - KEY_HOME
              KEY_COMMA:
                  - KEY_END
              KEY_H:
                  - KEY_DELETE
```

The "nice" applications still seem to work, as do chrome and qt apps. One downside is that you must specify your input device exactly instead of saying, say, "any keyboard". Another potential downside is that any other process trying to grab the keyboard will not manage to do it.